# Figuring out the margin for the soft margin SVM (exam question)

Tags: self-study, classification, svm

This is an exam question and I am not sure whether it is solveable with the given information.

We were given a graphic that displayed binary labelled points $x^{(i)}\in \mathbb{R}^2$ with $y^{(i)} \in \{-1,1\}$ in 2d space and a seperating line with equation:

$$2x_2=-2x_1+4\quad \quad (1)$$

This equation described the decision boundary for a **Soft margin SVM** with unknown complexity parameter $C$,  i.e.

$\min_{\theta, \theta_0, \zeta^{(i)}}\frac{1}{2}||\theta||^2 + C \sum_{i=1}^n\zeta^{(i)}$

$s.t. \quad y^{(i)}(\theta^Tx^{(i)}+\theta_0)\geq1-\zeta^{(i)}, \quad \zeta^{(i)}\geq0$

Our task was to find out the margin $\gamma= \frac{1}{||\theta||}$

So we were *only* given this information:

1. coordinates of the points + their label
2. equation for decision boundary

So again my question: is it even possible to solve this question and if so, how?

My first intention was to set $||\theta||=\sqrt{2^2+2^2}$, simply reading off the parameter values from equation $(1)$. However this is of course invalid as you can simply multiply the equation for the decision boundary with any arbitrary constant which makes this solution completely abitrary and incorrect.